# how to send photographer id in django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

How I send Photographer id in django rest framework. with post request. the current user is perfectly send but I want to send photographer id .
please help me to solve this probelm

Here is my code.

**models.py**

```py
class Booking(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    photographer = models.ForeignKey(photographer,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, 
    related_name="photographer_set")
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    near_by = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    phone_number = models.BigIntegerField(null=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today()
    
    @staticmethod
    def get_booking_by_customer(user_id):
        return Booking.objects.filter(user=user_id).order_by('_date')
```

**serializer.py**

```py
class bookingserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #photographer_set = photographerSerializer()
    #user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ['id', 'address','near_by','phone_number','date',"photographer",'user','status']
        depth = 1
```

**views.py**

```py
    class bookings(generics.GenericAPIView):
        permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
        serializer_class = bookingserializer
        @csrf_exempt
        def post(self, request):
            booking = request.data
            serializer = self.serializer_class(data=booking)
            #booking.status=True
            self.request.data.get('photographer_id')
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may pass in the `'photographer_id'` request body from frontend.

Then in your view.py, you could get the data with `self.request.data.get('photographer_id')`.

If you are using POSTMAN:

[image: image description]

Try below:

```
class bookings(generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = bookingserializer
    @csrf_exempt
    def post(self, request):
        booking = request.data
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=booking)
        #booking.status=True
        photographer_id = self.request.data.get('photographer_id')
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user, photographer=photographer_id)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: This is not working

Comment: If you are using postman, you may check according to the screenshot with edited answer.

Comment: I include your  self.request.data.get('photographer_id') this line in my code. but this is not working . In postman the all the details like address, near_by is send but the photographer_id is not send

Comment: You need to pass the data you get from frontend and save it. See the edited answer.